# How to justify SVG text to the right?

Tags: angular, svg, text, justify

I am using SVG to create some tables and put some text inside them. I can controll the placement of the text with SVG coordinates, but the text length is variable as it comes from some data. There is some way to get the length of the text or some other tool to justify it to the right?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### align right

Place your text on a `textPath`, set `pathLength=100`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath

`startoffset` and `text-anchor` take care of positioning

play with lower `startoffset` to add right-padding

[image]

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 200 50">
  <path id="P" pathLength="100" d="M0 25h200" stroke="blue"/>
  <text>
    <textPath href="#P" 
              startoffset="100" text-anchor="end" 
              dominant-baseline="middle"
              fill="green" font-size="14px">Right aligned</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```