# SVG lines with text on top

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have an SVG line & it gets moved around via js & I want to place some text along it, like this:
[image]

and every time the line moves the text should automatically move along with it while always staying in the center of the line no matter what the length

I tried a naive approach like this but it obviously didn't work:

```
<svg height="210" width="500">
<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2">
  Hello there
</line>

</svg>
```

is such a thing possible or will I have program the text to move as well in javascript?

Comment: See all 1994 text align answers previously given here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsvg%5D+text+align

Comment: **1.** You can use the line as [textPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath) **2.** You can draw a horizontal line, put it together with the text in a group and rotate the group

Comment: @enxaneta I'm looking into textPath, but I'm not sure groups will work as the line in question can change length and I don't think a group would be able to keep up with that, I might be wrong though

Comment: @enxaneta I tried [this](https://jsfiddle.net/0aqtnjd4/73/) with the textPath and it seems to work, the only problem is that I have to `xlink:href` within the textPath which will become a hassle once I have too many paths & can't add an id on every path, so is there a way to href without assigning an id? perhaps directly referencing the path in js?

Comment: Use the path attribute of the textPath `<textPath path="M0,0 L200,200"`

Comment: @enxaneta only works in [firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30654976/18005234), do you have any cross browser solution?

Comment: In this case go for the group solution

Comment: Convert the ``line`` to a ``path``, set ``pathLength``, use ``textPath``, no ``textLength`` adjustments needed for any X Y line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71082814/how-to-justify-svg-text-to-the-right/71085015#71085015

Answer (score 0):

> every time the line moves the text should automatically move along with it

I think the most straightforward way to go about this would be to:

- group the `<line>` and the `<text>` together using a `<g>`; and then
- transition or animate the `<g>` element with your javascript.

**N.B.** I've used a CSS animation rather than javascript in the example below but the principle holds.

---

**Working Example:**

```css
svg {
width: 500px; 
height: 210px;
}

g {
  transform-origin: 100%;
  animation: rotateGroup 3s linear infinite;
}

line {
  stroke: rgb(255,0,0);
  stroke-width: 4px;
}

text {
  fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  font-size: 36px;
}

@keyframes rotateGroup {
  0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 105 250">

<g>
  <line x1="0" y1="185" x2="200" y2="185" />
  <text x="22" y="176">Hello there</text>
</g>

</svg>
```

---

**Additional Note:**

You mentioned:

> while **always staying in the center** of the line no matter what the length

To achieve this you can recalculate the `x` value of `<text>` every time you recalculate the `x1` and `x2` values of `<line>`.

Comment: I think it would too much of a hassle trying to readjust every element in a group, I tried [this](https://jsfiddle.net/0aqtnjd4/73/) approach instead, I'm no expert in svg so could you take a look & tell me the limitations?

Comment: you can use the group but you may try  `<text x="92.5"` in the middle of the line and  `text-anchor="middle"`, This way you won't need to readjust for a different text